# WEBGL Fluid simulation

Tags: webgl, fragment-shader, fluid-dynamics

I am trying to get a fluid simulation to work using WebGL using http://meatfighter.com/fluiddynamics/GPU_Gems_Chapter_38.pdf as a resource. I have implemented everything but I feel like there are multiple things that aren't working correctly. I added boundaries but it seems like they are having no effect, which makes me suspicious about how much pressure and advection are working. I displayed the divergence and I get very little around where I am moving the object around as well as when the velocity hits the edge (boundary), but the pressure that I get is completely empty. I calculate pressure using the diffusion shader as described in the linked resource.

I know the code I am posting is al little confusing due to the nature of what it is about. I can supply any pictures/links to the simulation if that would help.

--EDIT--

After some more investigation I believe the problem is related to my advection function. or at least a problem. I am unsure how to fix it though.

Instead of posting all of my code, the general process I follow is:
advect velocity
diffuse velocity
add velocity
calculate divergence
compute pressure 
subtract gradient

for diffusing velocity and computing pressure I am only do 10 iterations because thats all my computer can handle with my implementation (I will optimize once I get it working), but I feel like the computing pressure and subtracting gradient are not having any effect.

here are the shaders I am using:

```
//advection
uniform vec2 res;//The width and height of our screen
uniform sampler2D velocity;//input velocity
uniform sampler2D quantity;//quantity to advect


void main() {
        vec2 pixel = gl_FragCoord.xy / res.xy;

        float i0, j0, i1, j1;
        float x, y, s0, s1, t0, t1, dxt0, dyt0;
        float dt = 1.0/60.0;
        float Nx = res.x -1.0;
        float Ny = res.y -1.0;
        float i = pixel.x;
        float j = pixel.y;

        dxt0 = dt  ;
        dyt0 = dt  ;
        x = gl_FragCoord.x - dxt0 * (texture2D(velocity, pixel).x );
        y = gl_FragCoord.y - dyt0 * (texture2D(velocity, pixel).y );

        i0=x-0.5; 
        i1=x+0.5;

        j0=y-0.5; 
        j1=y+0.5;


        s1 = x-i0; 
        s0 = 1.0-s1; 
        t1 = y-j0; 
        t0 = 1.0-t1;


        float p1 =  (t0 * texture2D(quantity, vec2(i0,j0)/res.xy).r);
        float p2 =  (t1 * texture2D(quantity, vec2(i0,j1)/res.xy).r);
        float p3 =  (t0 * texture2D(quantity, vec2(i1,j0)/res.xy).r);
        float p4 =  (t1 * texture2D(quantity, vec2(i1,j1)/res.xy).r);
        float total1 = s0 * (p1 + p2);
        float total2 = s1 * (p3 + p4);
        gl_FragColor.r = total1 + total2;

        p1 =  (t0 * texture2D(quantity, vec2(i0,j0)/res.xy).g);
        p2 =  (t1 * texture2D(quantity, vec2(i0,j1)/res.xy).g);
        p3 =  (t0 * texture2D(quantity, vec2(i1,j0)/res.xy).g);
        p4 =  (t1 * texture2D(quantity, vec2(i1,j1)/res.xy).g);
        total1 = s0 * (p1 + p2);
        total2 = s1 * (p3 + p4);
        gl_FragColor.g = total1 + total2;

}

//diffusion shader starts here

uniform vec2 res;//The width and height of our screen
uniform sampler2D x;//Our input texture
uniform sampler2D b;
uniform float alpha;
uniform float rBeta;


void main() {
    float xPixel = 1.0/res.x;
    float yPixel = 1.0/res.y;
    vec2 pixel = gl_FragCoord.xy / res.xy;
    gl_FragColor = texture2D( b, pixel );

    vec4 leftColor = texture2D(x,vec2(pixel.x-xPixel,pixel.y));
    vec4 rightColor = texture2D(x,vec2(pixel.x+xPixel,pixel.y));
    vec4 upColor = texture2D(x,vec2(pixel.x,pixel.y-yPixel));

    vec4 downColor = texture2D(x,vec2(pixel.x,pixel.y+yPixel));




    gl_FragColor.r = (gl_FragColor.r * alpha +leftColor.r   + rightColor.r + upColor.r + downColor.r) * rBeta;

    gl_FragColor.g = (gl_FragColor.g * alpha +leftColor.g   + rightColor.g + upColor.g + downColor.g)* rBeta;


    gl_FragColor.b = (gl_FragColor.b * alpha +leftColor.b   + rightColor.b + upColor.b + downColor.b)* rBeta;


}



//gradient
uniform vec2 res;//The width and height of our screen
uniform sampler2D velocity;//Our input velocity
uniform sampler2D pressure;//Our input pressure

void main() {
    float xPixel = 1.0/res.x;
    float yPixel = 1.0/res.y;
    vec2 pixel = gl_FragCoord.xy / res.xy;

    vec4 leftColor  = texture2D(pressure, vec2(pixel.x-xPixel,pixel.y));
    vec4 rightColor = texture2D(pressure, vec2(pixel.x+xPixel,pixel.y));
    vec4 upColor    = texture2D(pressure, vec2(pixel.x,pixel.y-yPixel));
    vec4 downColor  = texture2D(pressure, vec2(pixel.x,pixel.y+yPixel));




    vec2 gradient = xPixel/2.0 * vec2((rightColor.x - leftColor.x), (upColor.y - downColor.y));
    //Diffuse equation
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(velocity, pixel) ;
    gl_FragColor.xy -= gradient;



}



uniform vec2 res;//The width and height of our screen
uniform sampler2D velocity;//Our input texture


void main() {
    float xPixel = 1.0/res.x;
    float yPixel = 1.0/res.y;
    vec2 pixel = gl_FragCoord.xy / res.xy;

    vec4 leftColor  = texture2D(velocity, vec2(pixel.x-xPixel,pixel.y));
    vec4 rightColor = texture2D(velocity, vec2(pixel.x+xPixel,pixel.y));
    vec4 upColor    = texture2D(velocity, vec2(pixel.x,pixel.y-yPixel));
    vec4 downColor  = texture2D(velocity, vec2(pixel.x,pixel.y+yPixel));




    float div = xPixel/2.0 * ((rightColor.x - leftColor.x) + (upColor.y - downColor.y));
    //Diffuse equation
    gl_FragColor = vec4(div);



}
```